# Windows Azure for PHP: Compute emulator error

Tags: php, windows, azure

While carefully doing the steps on 'Build and deploy a Windows Azure PHP application' page on URL 'http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/build-and-deploy-a-windows-azure-php-application', I encounter the following errors in doing the 'Run the PHP application in the local development environment' step when running the command:

```
package create -in="C:\temp\WindowsAzurePHPApp" -out="C:\temp\WindowsAzurePHPApp\build" -dev=true
```

---

```
C:\>package create -in="C:\temp\WindowsAzurePHPApp" -out="C:\temp\WindowsAzurePH
PApp\build" -dev=true
Windows(R) Azure(TM) Packaging Tool version 1.4.0.0
for Microsoft(R) .NET Framework 3.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\temp\WindowsAzurePHPApp\ServiceDefinition.csdef (15, 12): Error  CloudService
s051 : The XML specification is not valid: The required attribute 'value' is mis
sing.
C:\temp\WindowsAzurePHPApp\ServiceDefinition.csdef (15, 37): Error  CloudService
s051 : The XML specification is not valid: The element cannot contain white spac
e. Content model is empty.
C:\temp\WindowsAzurePHPApp\ServiceDefinition.csdef (16, 14): Error  CloudService
s051 : The XML specification is not valid: The element 'http://schemas.microsoft
.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition:Variable' cannot contain child ele
ment 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition:Role
InstanceValue' because the parent element's content model is empty.
Windows(R) Azure(TM) Desktop Execution Tool version 1.4.0.0
for Microsoft(R) .NET Framework 3.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Starting the storage emulator...
Windows(R) Azure(TM) Desktop Execution Tool version 1.4.0.0
for Microsoft(R) .NET Framework 3.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Starting the compute emulator...
Windows(R) Azure(TM) Desktop Execution Tool version 1.4.0.0
for Microsoft(R) .NET Framework 3.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Using session id 1
Windows(R) Azure(TM) Desktop Execution Tool version 1.4.0.0
for Microsoft(R) .NET Framework 3.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Using session id 1
**The compute emulator had an unexpected error: Can't locate service descriptions.**
.
C:\temp\WindowsAzurePHPApp\build/WindowsAzurePHPApp.cspkg
C:\>
```

can anybody help on what I am missing or something?
I have done the steps on this page manually. Also done the Pre Requisites manually and carefully rev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is on line 15 of your ServiceDefinition.csdef file? I am guessing it will be the following

`<Variable name="EMULATED">
            <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
</Variable>`

Try commenting out that entire section by wrapping it with the normal HTML comment tags () and run the package command again.

Comment: Thanks Ben. It worked well. Aside from your solution, I would consider what MSTS suggested to use the latest SDK 1.6 as I am using 1.4. (I use 1.4 as suggested by their site)